# In Gradle, is there a way to do graceful degradation of repositories?

Tags: gradle, repository, artifactory, artifacts

On a complex project, we a set of build.gradle and settings.gradle files.  We are applying some settings to all subprojects.  We have 3 developers:  Developer A, B and C.  Each one uses a different set of repositories.   That is the key difference.

Developer A: They are able to use the standard mavenCentral().
Developer B: They can't reach mavenCentral, so they declare a maven {url "https://artifactory_a:port/artifactory/name"}
Developer C: They can't reach either of the above, so they declare a maven {url "https://artifactory_b:port/artifactory/othername"}

Ideally, I would like to have one central set of Gradle build files.  I would like to have either graceful degradation where there are 3 servers that are approved for pulling down dependencies and if the first one isn't reachable, then it tries the second one.  If that one fails, it tries the third.

OR

If we can't have graceful degradation, could we check for an ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE or some other condition  (maybe we create an empty file that defines the location and check for the existence of that file?) and based on the status of the conditional that would let us select which repository is defined?   This might be a good option because I would just check for 2 conditions and if neither are present, then I would go with the default configuration.

Comment: It’s Gradle, you can do whatever you want. The easiest is probably for each developer to set their repo in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` and to simply use a project property. But you can write arbitrarily complicated code to literally do _anything_ - e.g ping each host in turn and select based on the results

Comment: Thank you.  You make it sound simple, but I've been trying a lot of things, reading documentation, and there is something I'm just not getting.  That's why I asked.   I've got an existing project that I've gotten it to kind of work, but I would like to eventually get it to a point where it not only works, it works well regardless of which developer is working on it.   I am not able to share to project file, so I'm stuck trying to deal with simple real world cases and then applying it to my situation.    I've made progress, but "you can do whatever you want" ---  that's really easy to say.

Comment: I think one thing that may help me is to try and use this: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:custom-maven-repo where it talked about "Setting up composite Maven repositories".   I'm not sure how to set that in the gradle.properties file, but I'm going to give it a try.